# Prevent alert boxes from appearing in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I can use this in my Opera browser to stop the alert boxes from appearing:

```
javascript:function alert () {}
```

However, it does not work whenever I use this in Firefox. What is the command to stop the alerts in Firefox?

Comment: try `window.alert = function() {};`

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done like this

```
window.alert = function() { return false; }
```

But, if you want to stop the alert boxes, best solution is **not to use `alert()`** at all.
Disabling the JavaScript functions in not right solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming given your use of `javascript:` that you're trying to do this by pasting javascript code directly into the location bar. If so the other suggestions on this page aren't going to help you because [as of Firefox 6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Firefox_6_for_developers), `javascript:` URIs execute outside the context of the page:

> For security reasons, data: and javascript: URIs no longer inherit the
>   security context of the current page when the user enters them in the
>   location bar; instead, a new, empty, security context is created. This
>   means that script loaded by entering javascript: URIs in the location
>   bar no longer has access to DOM methods and the like, for example.
>   These URIs continue to work as before when used by script, however.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
window.alert = function() {};
```